# MSSQL server 2014 of plesk is connecting to my Management Studio 2016

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, plesk

I have an issue regarding Plesk and MS SQL Server Management Studio, I do not connect my newly created database on Plesk with my SQL Server Management Studio can you please help to figure out this issue.

Comment: What you are asking here is very unclear. What do you mean *" I do not connect my newly created database on Plesk with my SQL Server Management Studio"*. Are you getting an error? Figure out what issue?

Comment: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000435973-How-to-add-already-installed-MSSQL-server-in-Plesk-

Comment: I am error that is server instance is not found

Answer (score 1):

I just change the host and enter the user credentials it works

Comment: Hello, ALi Sufian. Once you are answering your own question, please consider marking it as the right answer to help other.